# Is there a way to add zoom in and out buttons on Evince's toolbar?

Tags: pdf, evince, zooming

is there a way to add a "zoom in" and "zoom out" button in evince's panel? The scrolldown menu with 100%, 85%, fit to screen etc. is not very userfriendly.

Unfortunately I can't find a settings menu. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Evince and right-click on toolbar - context menu with one action will be shown, named "Toolbar". Click on it, then drag zoom-in and zoom-out buttons on toolbar